# read array after decoding from json Google Maps

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, maps

I have a problem I can not understand how I can get the field long_name example of address_components of 'array generated writing this script:

```
$url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.$lat.','.$lng.'&sensor=true';
$data = @file_get_contents($url);
$jsondata = json_decode($data , true);

if(is_array($jsondata ))
{
      $long_name= $jsondata ['results']['address_components'][0]['long_name'];
}
```

look a suggestion

thanks

Answer (score 0):

`$results` is an array. If you want to get the first result:

```
$jsondata ['results'][0]['address_components'][0]['long_name']
```